# Remove literals from input mask after form submit?

Tags: jquery, plugins, mask, maskedinput

this question has already been asked but the solutions where not clear.

Im using Josh Bush's MaskedInput plugin for jQuery

What im trying to achieve is:

E.g: a phone input with the mask

```
    $("#txtPhone").mask("(99)9999-9999");
```

EQUALS: (00)9398-8373

i want it to submit : 0093988373

------ Is it possible to remove the .mask on submit but keep the value?

Comment: You could just use .replace(/()-/g, '').  Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you want to use `unmask`

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
  $("#txtPhone").unmask();
});
```

Comment: Much more elegant than my solution. +1

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOP, ty ty :D

Comment: The empty literals are removed but the ones with values still have the literals. Should we use replace() for that?

Comment: not working unmask func. 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).unmask is not a function

Comment: No longer working. `$(...).unmask is not a function`.

Comment: Adding on your solution, if you have multiple fields (my case): `$('.unmask').unmask()`

Answer (score 16):

Set removeMaskOnSubmit as true when you initialize the inputmask

```
    $("#txtPhone").inputmask({removeMaskOnSubmit: true});
```

Comment: This code you submit is relative to `jquery.inputmask` from "Robin Herbots" ( https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask ).

This does not work on Josh Bush's `jquery.maskedinput` ( https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput ).

Comment: Yes your are right, do you want me to delete the answer?

Answer (score 8):

Based on [Plugin Site](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/issues/58):

```
$("#txtPhone").val($("#txtPhone").mask());
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me! Applied on form submit

Comment: This is the best way to accomplish task

Comment: Thank you for this one!

Answer (score 7):

unmask is not a function. This is my way of use. ***autoUnmask: true***

```
    $('#amount').inputmask('999.999.999.999', {
        numericInput: true,
        autoUnmask: true,
    });
```

Comment: Should probably note that this function is available through a jQuery plugin and not base jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the completed callback, then you can just use:

```
$(element).mask("(99)9999-9999", {
  completed : function () {
    var numbers = this.val().replace(/()-/g,'');
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you can use:

`$(element).val().replace(/()-/g,'');`

If you want to do this before submitting, I suggesting capturing the submit event, using the code immediately above and then submitting the form.

**EDIT:** Alex Peattie pointed out the `unmask()` function, which I must say is a much better solution than mine.  I'll leave my answer here, but I'd go with his solution.

Comment: TY vm @Ivan// i will keep your solution in mind for other coding that dont using the .mask plugin

Comment: Using a regexp didn't work for me. I am using the same mask plugin with the following pattern: $?999. .replace(/$_/g,'') did not work. I tried escaping the $ with a backslash and that didn't work. For now I am using .replace('$','').replace(/_/g,'') and that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also extract the raw value on a masked input using

```
$("#YourSelector").data( $.mask.dataName )();
```

Source : https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/issues/318

**Example**
If you use a `phone` input with such a mask :

```
$(".phone").mask("99 99 99 99 99")
```

you can extract the user input using :

```
$(".phone").data($.mask.dataName)() 
// will produce "0102030405" while the masks displays 01 02 03 04 05
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have more than just one input being submitted, you could use:

```
// unmask all inputs, before savinf;
$(FormObj+" input[type=text]").each(function() {
    $(this).unmask();
});
```

where FormObj is your form object id, such as #form.