# jQuery mask input without changing value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [masked-input-plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) but it changes value and field becomes invalid ...

in my js

```
$phoneInput.mask('99-99-99-999');
```

and later in browser console

```
('.phone-input-order-form').val()
"99-99-99-999"
```

Is there any way to get from `val` `"999999999"` while it masked ?

I am thinking to extend jQuery `val` but maybe you know better way? maybe without this plugin? :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove literals from input mask after form submit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854651/remove-literals-from-input-mask-after-form-submit)

Comment: So basically you want to void doing that every single time?

Comment: seems I asked clearly - 1) or extend `val`; 2) or somehow show mask without affect to inputs value

Comment: @stevenw00 nope, It's not DRY There are many lines of code where I should add condition and put unmask or replace or whatever ...

Comment: what about a **newer** prototype so that you won't need to extend .val()? do you have to replace that .val() so many times? something like that? http://jsfiddle.net/jvr0nqz2/

Comment: @briosheje I have took idea from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5007327/3033586

Comment: @madzohan: Not sure, I feel that it is easier to create a new prototype, but maybe it's just me.

Comment: If you change `val` things will probably stops working, because inside masked-input-plugin it also uses `val`, so it creates some kind of circular dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding jQuery's `val()` function might cause unexpected issues with other scripts. Maybe try something like this:

```
$.fn.maskVal = function () {
    return $(this).mask();
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/w4s0v7y3/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.phone-input-order-form').mask(); => "999999999"
```

Answer (score -1):

do something like

```
yourstring.replace("-", "");
```

Comment: It's not DRY There are many lines of code where I should add condition and put `replace`