# Symfony 3.4: apply mask to MoneyType field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

I'm working with Symfony 3.4 and I'm trying to apply mask for my MoneyType | NumberType field,

The purpose of the mask is to act in the Front to make :

**1) Format the number (obligatory):**

```
12000.5 => 12 000.5

1234567.2 => 1 234 567.2
```

**2) Disable non numeric Field (optionally):**

When the user try to tap a character, the input never change.

For that I try to work with JQuery Libraries, but I get an issue when submitting the form, the backend considers that the input is not a number so the $form->isValid() is not satisfied

## FormType:

```
->add('prixUnit', NumberType::class, array(
  "grouping" => true, //works only on show mode not on newAction
  'attr' => array(
    "class" => "number"
    "min" => 0,
    "step" => 0.100,
    "placeholder" => "0.000",

  )
))
```

## Twig:

```
$('.number').maskSomeLibrariesJquery();
```

I'm searching for a clean Symfony Solution to format my field without having problems in the backend.

Comment: You can remove the mask on submited data to avoid type error.
Lokk a this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854651/remove-literals-from-input-mask-after-form-submit

Comment: Yes that's the solution that I had adapt but it rest the case when the User refresh the page, I have to unmask the input before it refresh the page! But the codes to handle refresh event doesn't work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [this jquery plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/maskMoney/), here is an [example](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/). With this plugin you could choose your separator with the decimal option, by default is dot(".") but yyou could change it by space(" ").

Also can be configured by attributes

```
<input type="text" data-symbol="R$ " data-thousands="." data-decimal="," />
```

Also there are some tips like:

> **.maskMoney('unmasked')** **return a float value (ex.: 'R$ 1.234,56' =>
>   1234.56)**. PS: If you have only one input field, you should use this way .maskMoney('unmasked')[0], since it will always return an array.

Hope it helps!